# Use the compound interest formula to calculate the interest rate for an account that was compounded semi-annually and ...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Use the compound interest formula to calculate the interest rate for an account that was compounded semi-annually, had an initial deposit of \$9,000 and was worth \$13,373.53 after 10 years.

Formula: $A(t)=P(1+\frac{r}{n})^{nt}$

The solution provided in my book is 4% whereas I get an absurd answer -94%. I'd like to understand where I went wrong. My working:

$n=2$
$P=9000$
$A(t)=13373.53$
$t=10$

Plugging the above into the formula with granular steps to isolate where I went wrong:
$$13373.53=9000(1+\frac{r}{2})^{2*10}$$
$$13373.53=9000(1+\frac{r}{2})^{20}$$
$$\frac{13373.53}{9000}=(1+\frac{r}{2})^{20}$$
$$1.48595=(1+\frac{r}{2})^{20}$$
$$2(1.48595)=2(1+\frac{r}{2})^{20}$$
$$2.972=(2+r)^{20}$$
$$2.972^{\frac{1}{20}}=2+r$$
$$r=2.972^{\frac{1}{20}}-2$$
$$r=-0.944$$

Where did I go wrong and how can I arrive at 4%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is just after $$1.48595=\left(1+\frac{r}{2}\right)^{20}$$ You have now
$$\sqrt[20]{1.48595}=1+\frac{r}{2}\implies r=0.04$$

Answer (score 1):

The wrong step is:

> $$2(1.48595) = 2(1+\frac r2)^{20}$$
> $$2.972 = (2+r)^{20}$$

Since $$(2+r)^{20} = (2(1+\frac r2))^{20} = 2^{20}(1+\frac r2)^{20} \ne 2(1+\frac r2)^{20}$$

Multiplying by $2$ in the previous step is unnecessary; we can take the root right then and there.